# Elasticsearch Searchkick - Reindex doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have pulled a new version of our application from git (upgraded to Ruby 2.6.5 and Rails 6) and run "`rake db:create db:migrate db:seed`" and my application is up and running fine. However, when I try to visit the page that lists our "Strength" models I get this:

```
#<Searchkick::MissingIndexError: Index missing - run Strength.reindex>
```

I am also seeing this for other models. Following the error suggestion I tried running reindex on all the models - I tried individually with "`rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=XXX`" and then I tried reindexing all with:

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake searchkick:reindex:all
```

The output suggested the reindexing was performed and completed successfully - I got no errors back. However, the MissingIndexError remains.

Comment: Are you reindexing the correct database? The environment is set to development in your command above - is it the production database that you are trying to reindex?